# Asynchronous PHP script stops when main script stops

Tags: php, windows, asynchronous, process

I spent some time trying to find a way on Windows to have a PHP script start another script asynchronously, and came across a suggested solution of using *popen()*. It didn't seem to work at first, but then when I added a delay it seemed to work a bit better. But on further investigation, it seems that shortly after the main script ends, the secondary process is killed.

Here's the relevant bit of code that launches the secondary script...

```
$cmd = <<<EOT
start "php" /b "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\iis express\\PHP\\v7.1\\php.exe" -f="$script" $args
EOT;
$p = popen($cmd, 'r');
usleep(500000);
pclose($p);
```

And the relevant part of the secondary script...

```
$fp = fopen($argv[1] . '.txt', 'w');
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    fwrite($fp, $i ."\n");
    sleep(1);
}
fclose($fp);
```

This is just proof-of-concept stuff. Basically, the second script opens a file and then writes numbers from 0 to 99 at 1-second intervals.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to finish.  If the sleep is for 500ms it only gets to about 15.  For 200ms it gets to around 8, etc.

I'm guessing that it's some sort of process ownership issue. E.g. when the primary script terminates it kills off child processes, but I'm not sure and have run out of ideas of what else to try.

(Running IIS on Windows 10)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it on windows like so: using COM and `WScript.Shell`

```
$WshShell = new COM('WScript.Shell');
$cmd = 'cmd /C php '.$script;
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
```

This only works on windows, on Linux you can run it.

```
$cmd = 'php -f '.$script.' > /dev/null &';
exec($cmd, $oExec);
```

Both run a non-blocking background process.  This does assume you added the path to the `php.exe` to your environmental variables in windows, if not you can use the full path to the executable.

Don't ask me how many hours I spent figuring this out, it was a few.  As for `popen` well I never got that to work either, but than sending info to it through a pipe or whatnot wasn't a concern for me.

Comment: That's great! I managed to get it to work with just "php", but that's actually not the version I want to run right now, and using the full path just seemed to disappear. Any ideas?

Comment: not the version of PHP?, check what php.exe is assigned in your environmental variables ( for path ).  Personally I run 7 for Apache and 5.5 for the CLI, so when I unit test I can test it against that version lol

Comment: You can refer to this if you don't know how to change it, https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/

Comment: I run different versions on different ports (5.6 on 8080 and 7.1 on 80). In the end I did just update the path because that seemed easier. Still curious as to why it doesn't work with full path, but maybe that's for another day. :)

Comment: This was working great UNTIL I started trying to use shared memory. There seems to be some sort of permission conflict between the originating process and the one started by WScript.Shell. Any ideas about how to make sure the new process inherits the current one's permissions?